# How to keep contents with flexible height inside a div with a fixed one?

Tags: html, css

```css
    .container{
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .header{
        height: 20px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .content-upper{
        max-height: 230px;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .content-lower{
        min-height: 50px;
        max-height: 100px;
        background-color: teal;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Lorizzle</div>
    <div class="content-upper" contenteditable>Lorizzle tellivizzle boofron uhuh ... yih! amizzle, mofo adipiscing  nisl ma nizzle nisi. Shit dawg quam, break it down gangsta crunk, pot vitae, fo shizzle uhuh ... yih!, rizzle. Lorizzle tellivizzle boofron uhuh ... yih! amizzle, mofo adipiscing  nisl ma nizzle nisi. Shit dawg quam, break it down gangsta crunk, pot vitae, fo shizzle uhuh ... yih!, rizzle.</div>
    <div class="content-lower" contenteditable>Lorizzle tellivizzle boofron uhuh ... yih! amizzle, mofo adipiscing  nisl ma nizzle nisi. Shit dawg quam, break it down gangsta crunk, pot vitae, fo shizzle uhuh ... yih!, rizzle.</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zacy239v/1/

So here we have a container with the other three divs being inside it in that order. `content-upper` doesn't have a min-height, so it should shrink when `content-lower` becomes bigger, but it doesn't. Instead `content-lower` expands downwards even if I've set `bottom` to 0. If I set `container`'s overflow to hidden it will just cut from `content-lower`. Is there a way to make `content-upper` shrink when there isn't enough space?

Comment: @Justinas that sets the max height as the hight of the container, making the element bigger and still not shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. I hope this helps
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zacy239v/8/)

I have just used

```
.container{
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-bottom: 90px
}
```

Comment: I can't see what you are tryint to do. `content-lower` is almost entirely outside of `container` now. I need everything to fit in `container`

Comment: Ok in that case set width to 100% for .content-lower

Comment: It still goes outside of `container`. The whole thing should always fit inside of `container`'s dimensions. `content-lower` has some limited flexibility in terms of height and `content-upper` should fill the space between `content-lower` and `header`. I don't know how to express myself better. btw in jsfiddle you can click "run" just to test how the whole thing works and click "update" when you want to make a link for sharing.

Comment: The updated fiddle seems to meet OP's requirements *if* `padding-bottom: 50px;` is removed from `.container`.

Comment: padding-bottom is fixed by the content-lower height and since it is in the position: absolute it will automatically set in the bottom of its parent container. So to avoid that we will be using padding-bottom for the parent container